# Cambiar formato de DatePickerDialog: "d-m-yyyy" a "dd-mm-yyyy"

Tags: android, date, datepicker

Quiero que al seleccionar una fecha por el calendario me devuelva el formato de dos dígitos en el día y mes (dd-mm-yyyy) pero solo me devuelve uno (d-m-yyyy)

Podría alguien con esto, les dejo el código que estoy implementando

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
ImageView btn = findViewById(R.id.btnCalender);
final int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
final int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
final int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
final TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.calender);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(CrearActividad.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        monthOfYear = monthOfYear + 1;
                        tv.setText(year + "-" + monthOfYear + "-" + dayOfMonth);
                    }
                },year,month,day);
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hazlo a mano con un if. Si el día es más pequeño que 10, añadele un 0. Lo mismo con el mes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hacerlo con un if, es una opcíon válida (y viendo las [propiedades](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog), creo que la única).

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {

    int month = monthOfYear + 1;
    String formattedMonth = "" + month;
    String formattedDayOfMonth = "" + dayOfMonth;

    if(month < 10){

        formattedMonth = "0" + month;
    }
    if(dayOfMonth < 10){

        formattedDayOfMonth = "0" + dayOfMonth;
    }
    tv.setText(formattedDayOfMonth + "-" + formattedMonth + "-" + year);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme, me ha salido tal como lo mostraste arribe

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo me parece que la solución anterior funciona pero no es la ideal,
Les sugiero esta solución:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
Date date = cal.getTime();
fechaFormateada=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date);
```